# How to quickly iterate through an array in python

Tags: python

I'm learning python, and I found myself on some bottleneck I don't understand.

The part where I wrote on the file is quick, but the iteration or maybe the creation of the list is really slow.

This snippet runs in something less than a second and it's not possible.

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

```
import sys
import time

t0=time.time() 
arr=list(range(1,10000))
for i in arr:
    arr[arr.index(i)]= 'dsaijhjsdha' + str(i) + '\n'

open("bla.txt", "wb").write(bytearray(''.join(arr),'utf-8'))
d=time.time()-t0
print ("duration: %.2f s." % d)
```

Comment: What do you mean _"It is not possible"_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import sys
import time

t0=time.time() 
arr=list(range(1,10000))
for i in arr:
    arr[i-1]= 'dsaijhjsdha' + str(i) + '\n'

open("bla.txt", "wb").write(bytearray(''.join(arr),'utf-8'))
d=time.time()-t0
print ("duration: %.2f s." % d)
```

Have a look at the above solution.
This will achieve the same output as you want.

`Output: duration: 0.02 s.`

Comment: Thanks! So one problem was the arr.index

Comment: Exactly @porkaloca

Answer (score 1):

You can do all of this in one line with list comprehension as:

Use this:

```
arr = ['dsaijhjsdha' + str(i) + '\n' for i in range(1, 10000)]    
print(arr)
```

instead of:

```
arr=list(range(1,10000))
for i in arr:
    arr[arr.index(i)]= 'dsaijhjsdha' + str(i) + '\n'
```

Using `arr.index(i)` is unnecessarily adding to the cost of computation.

Comment: btw, it is called `list` in Python and not `array`.

Comment: So, the loop extends the list and fill it at the same time, correct? In python, there is no cost in re-dimensioning a list?

Comment: yes, no extra cost with re-demensioning with list comprehension. you can read more about how [list comprehension works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it) in detail.